# Trigger Android Studio to show method signature?

Tags: android, android-studio

is there a shortcut to force Android Studio to show the method signature?
Then I firstly want to call a method I see it:
[image]

But then when I leave this and reenter the signature I dont see it anymore:
[image]

Comment: `ctrl+p` is the shorcut

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this really what you are talking about? This command name is "Parameter info".

On Windows, it's assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> by default.

On Mac, it's assigned to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> by default.

You can change the keys as well from setting.

Answer (score 5):

Use "Ctrl+p" to get Method Parameter info in android studio.